# Using `auto` yields error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, c++98

I use VS2008 on Windows 10.
I have a problem with this function and hope you can help me

```
void CPythonNetworkStream::AppearShopSign(DWORD dwVID, std::string stSign) {
    if (stSign.empty())
        for (auto it = m_mapShopSign.begin(); it != m_mapShopSign.end(); ++it)
            if (dwVID == it->first)
                stSign = it->second;

    // LogBoxf("AppearShopSign: %u-%s", dwVID, stSign.c_str());
    PyCallClassMemberFunc(m_apoPhaseWnd[PHASE_WINDOW_GAME], "BINARY_PrivateShop_Appear", Py_BuildValue("(is)", dwVID, stSign.c_str()));
}
```

Error messages

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator' to 'int' 
error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
error C2227: left of '->first' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Comment: VS 2008 does not support `auto` type specifier.

Comment: `auto it ` not supported by VC++ 2008. You need to upgrade to one of the latest versions.

Comment: @LogicStuff It  probably does support the original C meaning of `auto`, but that's not what the OP is trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auto` keyword is supported since the c++11 standard, which isn't available with visual-studio 2008.

To fix that use an explicit type:

```
for (std::map<DWORD,std::string>::iterator it = m_mapShopSign.begin(); 
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     it != m_mapShopSign.end(); 
     ++it)
```

Comment: should be `const DWORD`

Comment: http://rextester.com/live/YSHPBV66254

Comment: @Viktor Do you have any evidence that the map was instantiated as `std::map<const DWORD,std::string>` from the given code? Your regextester example makes no difference, it's fine to deduce the `iterator` member type like this.

Comment: For evidence check the output from link I provided. `DWORD` is just `typedef`.

Comment: @Viktor Fine, my code works though. What may be the reason?

Comment: ok. I agree it is fine way.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `auto` was introduced in C++11 for [automatic type deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto). Before C++11 it was used to declare a local variable with automatic storage duration.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but I believe your latter paragraph applies for C standards only.